Representation determined by traces
Let $A$ be a unital algebra over the complex numbers and let $\pi,\pi':A\to M_n(\mathbb C)$ be two unital algebra homomorphisms. Assume both are surjective and their traces agree, i.e., $tr\ \pi(a)=tr\ \pi'(a)$ holds for every $a\in A$. Does it follow that they are conjugate, i.e., there exists an invertible matrix $S$ with $\pi'(a)=S\pi(a)S^{-1}$ for every $a\in A$? If so, is it a classical result?

It's true. Even without the finiteness assumption from the other answer. Here's a proof based on successive reduction steps.
Here's the statement that we're going to prove. Let $k$ be a field and $A$ be a $k$-algebra (all rings and algbras and modules in sight are assumed to be unital). Let $V$ and $W$ be simple, finite-dimensional (over $k$) $A$-modules that have the same traces. Then $V \cong W$ are isomorphic $A$-modules.
As in the other answer, we argue that the surjectivity of $\pi$ and $\pi'$ implies that $V$ and $W$ are simple.
First reduction step: stuff that acts trivially doesn't matter.
Let $u \in \mathrm{Ann}(V) \cap \mathrm{Ann}(W)$. This just means that $u$ acts trivially on $V$ and $W$. Then we clearly have $\operatorname{Tr}_V(a+u)=\operatorname{Tr}_V(a)$ for any $a \in A$ and the same for $W$. Also everything else about the setup is preserved if we just "ignore" everything that acts trivially on both $V$ and $W$ by which I mean if we replace $A$ by $A/\mathrm{Ann}(V) \cap \mathrm{Ann}(W)$.
Thus we can assume henceforth that $0=\mathrm{Ann}(V) \cap \mathrm{Ann}(W)$. But this means that $A$ acts faithfully on $V\oplus W$ and hence is finite-dimensional.
Second reduction step: The Jacobson Radical doesn't matter
Note that the Jacobson radical of $A$ acts trivially on all simple modules, in particular on both $V$ and $W$. Thus as in step one, we may replace $A$ by $A/\operatorname{rad}(A)$. Thus $A$ is finite-dimensional and has zero Jacobson radical, therefore $A$ is semisimple.
Third reduction step: Only one factor counts
By Artin-Wedderburn, we may write $A=\prod M_{n_i}(D_i)$ for some integers $n_i$ and f.d. division algebras $D_i$ over $k$.
Note that if we have a simple module over a product ring $A_1 \times A_2 \times \ldots \times A_\ell$, then it's isomorphic to a simple module over one of the $A_i$ with all other factors acting trivially.
So suppose in our situation that we have $i \neq j$ and a simple module $M_i$ over $M_{n_i}(D_i)$ and a simple module $M_j$ over $M_{n_j}(D_j)$ such that they induce modules with the same trace over $A=\prod M_{n_\ell}(D_\ell)$. Take any linear endomorphism $f$ of $D_i^{n_i}$ with trace $1$ (easily realizable through a diagonal matrix). Then we can pick $(0,\ldots, 0,f,0,\ldots,0) \in \prod M_{n_\ell}(D_\ell)$ with $f$ at the $i$-th place. This acts with trace $1$ on the module induced by $M_i$ and as $0$ on the module induced by $M_j$ as $i \neq j$.
This means if two f.d. simple modules over $A=\prod M_{n_i}(D_i)$ have the same trace, then they come from simple modules over one $M_{n_j}(D_j)$ for the same $j$.
The finishing step: Simple modules over $M_n(D)$ are really simple to understand
Now we just need to classify simple modules over $M_n(D)$ (and in theory compare their traces, but as we shall see, that's vacuous). But $M_n(D)$ for a division ring $D$ is simple Artinian, so there's only one simple module over it! (Concretely, $D^n$). This means that we're done.

Great answer! Thanks.

If we assume that $A$ is finite-dimensional, then the answer is yes. The maps $\pi$ and $\pi'$ define $A$-module strucutres on the vector space $\mathbb{C}^n$. The assumption that these maps are surjective means that these are simple $A$-modules. It is a fact that simple $A$-modules are isomorphic if and only if they have the same character (see e.g. Theorem 7.19 in Lam's book A First Course in Noncommutative Rings).
I don't know if there is a counterexample with $A$ infinite-dimensional.
